# Is CTE in PostgreSQL tail recursive?

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I wonder whether the recursive query in postgresql, for example the query below is tail recursive ?

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_tree(id, name, path) AS (
  SELECT id, name, ARRAY[id]
  FROM categories
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT categories.id, categories.name, path || categories.id
  FROM category_tree
  JOIN categories ON categories.parent_id=category_tree.id
  WHERE NOT categories.id = ANY(path)
)
SELECT * 
FROM category_tree 
ORDER BY path;
```

Comment: What would you like to know exactly? The real process behind the term `RECURSIVE`, as explained in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), is actually *iteration*. So yes, I guess you could define it *tail-recursive* in some sense...

Comment: Why? What's the underlying question, the reason you're asking this one? Do you want to know about halting behaviour?

Comment: @CraigRinger We can use the [Wikipedia *tail call* definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and say that the question is in a **performance context**. So the question is **CTE is implemented without adding a new stack frame when possible?**, or **is PostgreSQL's CTE optimized for *tail calls*?**